# Whats the standard approach to using region specific strings?

Tags: android, string

The app I work on will be launched in the UK, US and AU. I have strings.xml in values-en-rUS , values-en-rAU and values folders. I have certain strings for ex "Zipcode" which will only be used in the US so I have added them to strings.xml in values-en-rUS. I have "Postcode" as the equivalent in AU and UK strings.xml files.

This works fine as long as the device locale is set correctly ie, English(United states) in United states. If the device is in English (Australia) and the user is using the app in United states the solution fails.

Is there a standard approach for displaying a specific string irrespective of the device locale? Any help is appreciated

Answer (score 3):

I think you are using the wrong localization.
`values-en-rUS` you are defining resources in english (locale `en`) for mobiles situated in the US region.

If you use `values-en_US` instead it should correctly work for the locale `en_US`.

To better understand how the fallback between the different locales will happen consider this link:
[Android doc](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/multilingual-support.html)

Answer (score 2):

The correct Java SE standard usage is:

```
Locale:                     Properties file name part:

Locale("en", "US")          values_en_US
Locale("en", "AUS")         values_en_AUS
Locale("en", "UK")          values_en_UK
```

Best have a `Locale("en") / values_en` and `values` too.

There are some Locale constants. A small prototype will see whether this works satisfactory.